# Could rapid switching of opposing lasers heat a substance

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, kinetic-theory

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling

Lasers can effect the momentum so could you have two sets of lasers pointing in opposing directions rapidly alternating which set is on to increase vibration of the atoms or molecules and therefore rapidly heat them up efficiently.

If it was for dry air which wavelength and pulse rates would be best.

[image]

Comment: You are close to invent the laser driven microwave oven.

Comment: @user_na will that work, is that a thing, how efficient are they and how hot do they heat air?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient if the laser light were simply absorbed into the material?

Comment: I don't know? I was just thinking about it? How would your idea work? @Dave

Comment: @SRawes It would work like a hot lamp. Shine light on the thing, the thing absorbs that light and heats up. It's not totally clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to understand laser cooling? Light momentum? Are you proposing a new method of heating that you think is more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to heat a substance the lasers would have to have a frequency to match that substance. I think by matching frequency you would negate the purpose of alternating the directions of the lasers.  This is similar to how microwaves work in heating food by sending waves at the frequency of water so if you wanted to somehow emulate this using lasers you wouldn't need to alternate the lasers you would just need lasers that could match the frequency of the substance you wanted to heat.

Regarding heating air specifically it would depend on the volume of the container. Once you determine the volume of the container you could then calculate, using the equation U=cPmΔT, the amount of energy it would take to heat that area to a certain temperature and how long it would take. You could then transfer this to calculate whether or not it is feasible to have lasers of this energy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gas and a laser, and you want to heat up the gas, then normally the best thing you can do is to just shine the laser on the gas: the laser will deliver energy to the gas and this will tend to heat it up.

Under *very* specific conditions, it is possible to arrange things in such a way that the gas immediately re-radiates this energy away, and that it does so in a way that tends to reduce the disorder in the motion of the atoms in the gas. This is how laser cooling works.

In general, however, and away from those very specific conditions, lasers tend to heat matter up, not cool it down.